# How to make SQL Server return records that fall within any one of many time (or any value really) ranges defined in a separate table?

Tags: sql-server, sql

The code below clarifies the question in the title. What can be put in the WHERE to make it work?

```
CREATE TABLE #PickedTimes
(StartTime smalldatetime,
 EndTime smalldatetime)

INSERT INTO #PickedTimes
VALUES  ('2019-01-25 16:05', '2019-01-25 17:05'),
        ('2019-01-25 19:05', '2019-01-25 20:05')
--Each row is a time range. There would be more in the real situation, and it is desirable to define them this way.

SELECT * FROM #PickedTimes

-- No questions up to here.

SELECT TransactionID, Timestamp
FROM Transactions
WHERE Timestamp -- SOMETHING WITH #PickedTimes. How to make it pick any of the time ranges in #PickedTimes?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need this:

```
SELECT TransactionID, Timestamp
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN #PickedTimes
WHERE Transactions.Timestamp >= #PickedTimes.StartTime 
    AND Transactions.Timestamp <= #PickedTimes.EndTime
```